# Finding whether the given date and time is in Empty segment of DST

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst

My client and server are in UTC(+1245) Chatham Islands Time Zone

In this time zone, the clock will go one hour ahead from 30th Sep 2018 02:45 to 30th Sep 2018 03:45.

I want that if someone sets the time in-between these hours, it should notify the user. I have used the following code for finding it but it is not showing.

https://jsfiddle.net/tt8dmm4y/5/

```
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
  var jan = new Date(2018, 0, 1);
  var jul = new Date(2018, 6, 1);
  return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

Date.prototype.isDstObserved = function() {
  return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}

var checkdate = new Date(2018, 09, 30, 02, 55, 00);
if (checkdate.isDstObserved()) {
  alert("Daylight saving time!");
}
```

Any help?

Comment: How to get the time zones?

Comment: If DST happens as you describe, the time 02:55 that day won't exist, so what does it mean to ask whether DST holds that time?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson if user gives those values ,then how to identify that it is in empty DST segment ?

Comment: I suppose that if you get a valid date returned, you can check whether its hour and minute fields are equal to what you put in, but I'm not sure what the usual practice is when validating date fields. You have a bigger problem at the other end, when there are two possible interpretations during one hour.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object in JavaScript will always work in the time zone that is local to the user.  If you are comfortable with that, then simply compare the hours and minutes of the `Date` object with what you put in:

```
function isInvalidLocalTime(year, month, day, hour, minute) {
    var d = new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minute);
    return d.getHours() !== hour || d.getMinutes() !== minute;
}

isInvalidLocalTime(2018, 9, 30, 3, 0) // false, but only when local time is Chatham
```

When a time in a transitional gap is provided, the `Date` object will shift it to some other time (which way it shifts is implementation dependent in older browsers). Note that minutes are required, because some time zone offset transitions are only 30 minutes, and not all transitions are related to DST.

If you need it to be specific to a particular time zone instead of a user-local time zone, then you will need to use a library that supports such things and take a similar approach as above while specifying the time zone.  For example, we can use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) like this:

```
function isInvalidLocalTime(tz, year, month, day, hour, minute) {
    var dt = luxon.DateTime.fromObject({zone: tz, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hour, minute: minute});
    return dt.hour !== hour || dt.minute !== minute;
}

isInvalidLocalTime('Pacific/Chatham', 2018, 9, 30, 3, 0) // false
```

Also note that the `Date` object and Luxon's `DateTime` differ in whether months are zero-based or one-based.  I accounted for that above (both functions are 1-based), but in your code in the question - you were testing October, not September.